# Cypress - How to preserve session for complete test suite

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am testing adding and removing resource in my app. Currently it clears the cookies and does login and customer selection before each test case. My app checks if the cookies are gone then it redirects you back to login page.

```
describe("Resource Add / Remove", () => {
  let resourceName;
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost/myapp')
    
    const user = {
      email: EMAIL,
      password: PASSWORD,
    };
    cy.login(user);
    cy.selectCustomer('MyCustomer')
  });

  it("should create a new resource", () => {
    resourceName = "MyResource";
    // create new resource and check if it exist
  });

  it("it should delete last created resource", () => {
    // find resource using resourceName in the list and click on delete button
    // check if it is removed from the list
  });
});
```

But this is really time consuming... After creating a new resource I just want to jump to next test case and skip login and customer selection from the beginning.

How to do this?

In Cypress `preserveOnce` is now removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `cy.session()` correctly you need to add another `cy.visit()` after the session call.

That's because `cy.session()` is ***caching***.

That means the `cy.visit()` inside it's `setup` function is only called for the first test.

On the second test, you will get a blank page.

See [Where to call cy.visit()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Where-to-call-cyvisit) for further details.

```js
describe("Resource Add / Remove", () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.session(name, () => {
      cy.visit('http://localhost/myapp')    // only called on first test
    
      const user = {
        email: EMAIL,
        password: PASSWORD,
      };
      cy.login(user);
      cy.selectCustomer('MyCustomer')
    })
    cy.visit('http://localhost/myapp')       // visit here when cache is active
  })

  it("should create a new resource", () => {

  })

  it("it should delete last created resource", () => {

  })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is preserve a cookie, I recommend [cypress-v10-preserve-cookie](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-v10-preserve-cookie).

It has a very simple usage, just use it the same as the old `preserveOnce()`.

```js
import 'cypress-v10-preserve-cookie'

before(() => {
  // logging in here
  cy.setCookie('token', '123')
})

beforeEach(() => {
  // equivalent to cy.preserveCookieOnce('token')
  cy.preserveCookieOnce('token')
})

it('is logged in', () => {
  cy.getCookie('token')
    .should('have.property', 'value', '123')
})

it('is still logged in', () => {
  cy.getCookie('token')
    .should('have.property', 'value', '123')
})

it('is still logged in', () => {
  cy.getCookie('token')
    .should('have.property', 'value', '123')
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`cy.session()` should accomplish your goal of caching cookies. [From the documentation:](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session)

> Cache and restore cookies, localStorage, and sessionStorage (i.e. session data) in order to recreate a consistent browser context between tests.

In your case, it could look something like the following:

```js
describe("Resource Add / Remove", () => {
  let resourceName;
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.session(EMAIL, () => {
      cy.visit('http://localhost/myapp')
    
      const user = {
        email: EMAIL,
        password: PASSWORD,
      };
      cy.login(user);
      cy.selectCustomer('MyCustomer')
    });
  });

  it("should create a new resource", () => {
    resourceName = "MyResource";
    // create new resource and check if it exist
  });

  it("it should delete last created resource", () => {
    // find resource using resourceName in the list and click on delete button
    // check if it is removed from the list
  });
});
```

[However, Cypress recommends using `cy.session()` inside a custom login command.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Where-to-call-cysession)